# Is there any Python equivalent of R's biglm?

Tags: r, python, memory

I have used [biglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html) in R and found it very useful. Now I need the same type of functionality in python. Any ideas? I have seen that patsy/statsmodels has an incremental mode, but have not been able to find any samples to copy/adapt. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: This questions is a few years old now. Have there been any developments towards a working solution?

Answer (score 3):

from a related answer of Nathaniel Smith on the statsmodels mailing list

> My incremental LS code might be useful here, it's basically the same
>   problem:
>   https://github.com/njsmith/pyrerp/blob/master/pyrerp/incremental_ls.py#L330
>   The new X'X is the sum of the old X'Xs, then you have to re-do the
>   scaling and inversion to get the new vcov matrix for the estimates.
>   Should be doable so long as you know how many data points are in each
>   and the various sums-of-squares. (The code I linked has some extra
>   complexity because of handling a particular sort of heteroskedasticity
>   via FGLS, but it can pretty much be ignored.)

statsmodels doesn't have anything in this area yet.

There is an incremental OLS function in statsmodels, however that was written as helper function for cusum tests (in memory) and hasn't been used or checked for any other purpose:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.stats.diagnostic.recursive_olsresiduals.html